# android.process.acore has stopped

Tags: titanium-backup

I backed up one galaxy S3 and did a restore on another. Then I try to boot the new one and I get a message "Unfortunately the process android.process.acore has stopped". After hitting OK a few times I get Unfortunately TouchWiz has stopped. Then back to the first message. I can't get past this msg. 
I thought that maybe I should do another Restore but I can't get to anything cause this happens as soon as I boot.

Comment: Did both devices run the same Android version? If not, did you use the Migrate option in TB on restore? And did you restore system stuff -- or only your apps+settings? Restoring system stuff to a different device often is a bit tricky...

Comment: the Android on both are 4.0.4. No I did't check the Migrate option. But the build of the number of the Baseband are different. Could this be a problem? I selected Apps+settings I don't remember seeing an option for restoring system stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, never ever back up *system apps and settings* from one handset and restore to another, that is exactly what happens! :)

Mismatches with system app's key signature conflicts with another's ROM's key signature, and variants of settings as well may not exist on the other, all of those can lead to breakages such as what the OP is experiencing.

The only way to get that back, is to perform a factory reset to restore everything back to its original state.

Comment: How can I do a factory reset?

Comment: Go into Settings > Backup & reset > Factory data reset, that's in ICS fwiw :)

Comment: but the whole point is that I can't get to Settings! I can't get past this message.

Comment: Oo damn, my bad... hummm... get the original firmware for your handset and manually flash it with odin.

Comment: How would I know what that is? Did clockworkmod reocvery make a copy of it when it was flashed?

Comment: @Alex Failing to answer to your last comment - is both handsets rooted, does both have clockworkmod recovery? That should be part of your question above. I do not know if your CWM make a copy, when did you last use it?

Comment: @Alex You can do a factory reset without going via settings. Steps are described here: [Galaxy S3 - Factory Reset](http://factory-reset.com/wiki/Galaxy_S3).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this is what I did, and all back to good, now! thanks

Comment: Phew! Glad it all worked out @Alex :) \o/

Comment: I have this problem when restoring the backup from 6.0.1 build MMB29K to 6.0.1 build MOB30D.  After failing once, I reset and during next restore, I was careful enough to avoid any system app. But still the process crashed.:(